# How does Google Docs handle file uploads without an <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I working on an browser extension that looks for all input-nodes and listens to change handlers. My solution works on every possible page I have tried it on, except for docs.google.com when using this button:

[image]

---

- My initial guess was that they use document.createElement("input") but after scanning their source code I could not see any use case of this.
- When adding breakpoints in the source code I can see that there is a hidden <input> that is not placed in the DOM. I have no idea where this input is created.

[image]